# jQuery: selecting a span with a particular id

Tags: jquery

I'm getting an error message on this function telling me that parseInt doesn't have a radix parameter, even though I'm passing it the variable moveCount. I assume this means that the value of the span with the id #moveCount is not being assigned to the variable moveCount. I've marked the line below where I think the problem's arising. I've tried this line

```
moveCount = $('span #moveCount').html();
```

both with and without using the word 'span' in the selector and am getting the same result.

```
function incrementMoveCount() {
    //gets the html of the span with id
    //moveCount
    //turns it into a number
    //increments it by one
    //sets the html of the span with id moveCount
    //to the new move count
    var moveCount = 0; 
    var newMoveCount = 0;
    moveCount = $('span #moveCount').html();   # problem here
    newMoveCount = parseInt(moveCount);
    newMoveCount = newMoveCount + 1; 
    $('span #moveCount').html('newMoveCount');
}
```

html

```
<div id="meta">
<h1>Checkers</h1>
<h4>Moves: <span id="moveCount">0</span></h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove the space if it's the span's id - space specifies descendants.. so you are actually looking for descendants of span with an id=moveCount

```
$('span#moveCount').html();
```

Or since you are selecting by ID you don't need to specify span as ID selector is the fastest - ID's are unique so it will always look for the first element with that id

```
$('#moveCount').html();
```

Comment: ID's should be unique but it's not always the case. Better leave span element in selector if you are not sure.

Comment: @Dcortez not a good practice though.  ID's should always be unique on a page according to the specs https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the space...

```
moveCount = $('span#moveCount').html();
```

Your selector is selecting an element with an id `#moveCount` **within** a `span` element

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one element with the given id, you don't need to specify that it is a span.

```
$("#moveCount").html()
```

If that doesn't give you what you are looking for, the problem isn't in the jQuery code and we need to see html.

**Edit:**

```
$('#moveCount').html('newMoveCount');
```

should be

```
$('#moveCount').html(newMoveCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an element by id, you don't need the tag name to search it. Since, an HTML document should theoretically have only one element with a particular id. Thus in your case: $('#moveCount'); should also get you the element. I would change the code to be:

```
var moveCount = + $('#moveCount').text();
$('#moveCount').text(moveCount + 1);
```

The jquery .text() method will correctly get the value of the span and the '+' sign in front will automatically convert it to int. You don't need to call parseInt(). We can speeden it up further by firing the jQuery select just once:

```
var moveCountElement = $('#moveCount');
moveCountElement.text(+ moveCountElement.text() + 1);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
.html('newMoveCount');
```

means that the html of the span should be the string 'newMoveCount' not the value of newMoveCount variable. also there should be no space in between span and the id. All in all, this should work:

```
function incrementMoveCount() {
    var moveCount = 0;
    var newMoveCount = 0;
    moveCount = $('span#moveCount').html();
    newMoveCount = parseInt(moveCount);
    newMoveCount = newMoveCount + 1;
    $('span#moveCount').html(newMoveCount);
}
```